# Issue with pacman: "error: failed to prepare transaction"

Tags: arch-linux, manjaro, pacman

Trying to update my package database:

```
$ sudo pacman -Syu
[sudo] password for pietrom: 
:: Synchronizing package databases...
 core is up to date
 extra                                    1770.5 KiB   259K/s 00:07 [######################################] 100%
 community                                   5.3 MiB   150K/s 00:36 [######################################] 100%
 multilib is up to date
:: Starting full system upgrade...
warning: fontconfig: local (2:2.13.91+23+g65087ac-1) is newer than extra (2:2.13.1+12+g5f5ec56-2)
warning: lib32-systemd: local (243.9-1) is newer than multilib (242.135-1)
warning: python-pip: local (19.2.3-1.4) is newer than extra (19.2.3-1)
warning: systemd: local (243.9-1) is newer than core (242.135-1)
warning: systemd-libs: local (243.9-1) is newer than core (242.135-1)
warning: systemd-sysvcompat: local (243.9-1) is newer than core (242.135-1)
resolving dependencies...
looking for conflicting packages...
error: failed to prepare transaction (could not satisfy dependencies)
:: installing pamac-common (9.0.0-3) breaks dependency 'pamac-common<9.0.0' required by pamac-qt
```

Apart from the warnings about the newer versions already installed, what is and how can I fix the last error?

What I am trying to update is my LLVM/clang version (from 8 to 9), which I failed to do with Pacman.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`pacman` is telling you that it can't update the system, because it can't update a package without breaking a dependency.

You have a package installed called `pamac-qt`. This package is listed as "[experimental](https://wiki.manjaro.org/index.php/Pamac#Installing_Pamac)" and it [is not compatible with the pamac 9 API](https://forum.manjaro.org/t/pamac-conflicts/106411/4). You'll need to replace it with `pamac-gtk`.

This should fix your issue:

```
pacman -S pamac-gtk
pacman -R pamac-qt
```

Comment: Strange. With: `sudo pacman -Qi pacman-qt | grep Required` I get: "error: package 'pacman-qt' was not found". Trying to launch it from the GUI/KDE, nothing happens. It was working a few days ago. Could have it been uninstalled by the system automatically?

Comment: @Pietro the package listed in the output is `pamac-qt`, not `pacman-qt`, try that

Comment: Ops, I read too quickly; thank you. Now I get: "Required By : None"

Comment: @Pietro looks like you are free to delete it. If you know what it is and want to continue using it, install the AUR package that I mentioned

Comment: I successfully deleted `pamac-qt` and `pamac-common`. With `sudo pacman -U pamac-qt-git` I get the error "could not find or read package". Is it in a different repository? How can I access it? (I am new to Arch/Manjaro)

Comment: @Pietro your question is tagged Arch, but you're using Manjaro (also tagged), right? I didn't notice the second tag. Let me update the answer

Comment: Done. Now I have two new tools: "Add/Remove Software" and "Software Update". From here I selected clang+llvm-binaries, pushed on the "Build" button, and it has been "Preparing..." for ten minutes and counting...

Comment: @Pietro sounds like it's working

Comment: Not really. It is still "Preparing..."

Comment: Killed the "Software Update" "Preparing...". Launched "Add/Remove Software", and this is working properly. Only issue is that to install a new compiler it is updating the whole system...

Comment: @Pietro earlier, you were attempting `pacman -Syu`, `y` means refresh and `u` means system upgrade. That's why this is happening. If you want to install a package using pacman, use `pacman -S packagename`

Answer (score 1):

The best solution to resolve this issue is to remove all broken dependencies manually and then rerun `sudo pacman -Syu` command. It works!

Answer (score 0):

Remove the package and all its dependent packages:

```bash
sudo pacman -Runcs <package-name>
```

Then you can update the system and reinstall the package if needed.

```bash
-u, --unneeded       remove unneeded packages
-n, --nosave         remove configuration files
-c, --cascade        remove packages and all packages that depend on them
-s, --recursive      remove unnecessary dependencies
```